# How does Gyro Gearloose's security system work?

Tags: dos, ducktales-the-quest-for-gold

In the DOS version of [DuckTales: The Quest for Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DuckTales:_The_Quest_for_Gold), there is a security system, where you must prove, that you are not a [Beagle Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beagle_Boys).

[image: screenshot from DuckTales: The Quest for Gold]

Unfortunately, I can't solve this. I'm not good in English, so maybe, I'm missing something...

More screenshots: [erorC.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erorC.png), [2D90r.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D90r.png), [wKvCY.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKvCY.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to that wikipedia page,

> The Amiga and DOS game features copy protection in the form of a unique password system. When the game is booted up, **you must use a key script (located in the game manual)** to translate symbols on the screen. [..] there is no way to play the game without deciphering the code.

A copy of the manual can be found [here](http://www.mocagh.org/lucasfilm/classictales-manual.pdf).

[image: Manual page]

---

However, just a side-note:  it *is* possible to break the code without the manual.

Note that in your 3rd and 4th screenshots, both codewords begin with a 'C'.  Given the choices available in each of these, this means the code-word 'C' must be deciphered to either F, R, or W.

Additionally, pictures 2 and 4 contain an '8'.  Given the choices, '8' must be either M, G, U, or V.

Combining the previous two paragraphs and looking at picture 4, we know either 'C'=R, '8'=U; or 'C'=W, '8'=G.

If you continue this logic using more screenshots of codewords with matching characters, you'll eventually decipher every letter.

Comment: Is the code randomly generated each time you play?